# How do I refer to MovieClips / variables of the main .fla file from inside a MovieClip class?

Tags: actionscript-3

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class OtherMc extends MovieClip
    {
        public function OtherMc()
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eframe);
        }
        private function eframe(event:Event):void
        {
            if (hitTestObject(MainPacI))
            {
                trace("All Good");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a MovieClip instance on the stage of the mail .fla file called MainPacI and when I run the program, I get the error - 1120:Access of undefined property MainPacI. I apologize if the question is stupid, but I really need to know.

Regards,

Dust

Comment: MainPacI is As linkage or name?

Comment: If `MainPacI` is the instance name, then where are you creating it? There is no indication within your code.

Comment: I'll tell you what I did in detail. First, I drew the object using circle tool and then converted it to MovieClip Symbol. Then for the MovieClip on the stage, I gave the instance name MainPacI, should I still declare it in the code?

Comment: @otololua Ok, forget about a MovieClip, how do I refer to a variable declared in the stage of main .fla from inside the class.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following

`stage.MainPacI`

Comment: It gives a new error - 1119: Access of possibly undefined property MainPacI through a reference with static type flash.display:Stage.

Comment: Be sure to CHECK this box: http://i.stack.imgur.com/tXWzD.png. This way designer's instances should be automatically declared on stage.

Comment: Ok, forget about a MovieClip, how do I refer to a variable declared in the stage of main .fla from inside the class.

Comment: You can't. When you declare a variable in the FLA it's only valid in that context. You should have a Main Class in an external .as, and use it as Main Class for the FLA. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-a-document-class-in-flash--active-3233 (see image http://activetuts.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/071_QTdocClass/-2.jpg)